# Group BY with PK

Tags: sql

I need to be able to return the table id in a clustered query. Is there any way to use group by returning a given data without considering the same in grouping? Example:

HQL

```
select 
fichaProc.ID, -- PK 
fichaProc.procedimento.id, -- COLUMN WANT TO CONSIDER IN THE GROUPING
sum(fichaProc.qtd), 
sum(fichaProc.valorProc)
from XXX
group by fichaProc.procedimento.id
```

Comment: by *hql*..did you mean `HiveQL`?

Comment: Do you want a SQL solution or a HQL (=Hibernate) solution?

Comment: The above query will not execute, you will get error. Include `fichaproc.id` in  group by

Comment: `MAX(fichaProc.ID)` or `MIN`?

Comment: I prefer the solution in HQL

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* from XXX a join (
select 
fichaProc.ID,
sum(fichaProc.qtd), 
sum(fichaProc.valorProc)
from XXX
group by fichaProc.id) b on a.id=b.id
```

Comment: Sorry, what I want is impassible. I'll work on another solution.